# Static assets upload returns 404 in production nextjs

Tags: node.js, next.js

In production, when I upload an image to the public folder, next.js returns a 404 error when trying to view the image. I have to restart the server for next.js to respond with a 200 to the request.
In dev mode, it works without needing to restart or recompile.

```
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const mv = require("mv");

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async (req, res) => {
  const imageId = v4();

  const form = new IncomingForm();

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    const oldPath = files.file.filepath;
    const newImageId =
      imageId +
      files.file.originalFilename.substr(
        files.file.originalFilename.lastIndexOf(".")
      );
    const newPath = `./public/img/${newImageId}`;
    mv(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {});
    res.status(200).json({ fields, files, imageId: newImageId });
  });
};
```

I expect the same behavior as dev mode, the image should be displayed after upload and without the need to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been asked on the github repo of Nextjs. It is the expected behavior for some security reasons.

> This is expected behavior as per https://github.com/zeit/next.js/releases/tag/v9.3.2. It's done to prevent accidentally leaking files that should not be accessed.

See the link below.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12656

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

NextJs accesses the public folder, one race when building in production mode. In developer mode, the server is updated automatically when it changes. Try using custom express server.